# Perl script for e-mail responder has problems with HTML-formatted e-mails

Tags: html, perl, email, attachment

I am writing an e-mail auto-responder using Perl and the module `Mail::Message`. I want the script to respond to the sender with some text at the top and the body of the original sent e-mail at the bottom.

It is important for my application that text of the original e-mail included on the bottom is cut-and-paste'able.

Here is the code:

```
use Mail::Message;
use Perl6::Slurp;                                
my $email_text = slurp \*STDIN;
my $mail_message = Mail::Message->read($email_text);             
my $reply = $mail_message->reply(
  'prelude' => $prelude,
  'include' => 'ATTACH',
);
$reply->send();
```

This works fine if the body of the original e-mail sent was sent as plain text. However, if the sender composed their message using HTML, the e-mail response contains literal HTML. That is, if the sender were to send an e-mail message that was "**Hello**, *world*.", the sender gets an e-mail back that looks something like this:

```
Our Help Desk cannot respond to individual e-mails, 
but please file a ticket using our web form at
https://fake.fake/fake. 

Your original message is included below:

[Your message is attached]

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
      charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <b>Hello</b>, <i>world</i>.<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the body of the original message (the one sent to the auto-responder):

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------020206020509070600040305"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------020206020509070600040305
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

*Hello*, /world/.

--------------020206020509070600040305
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
      charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <b>Hello</b>, <i>world</i>.<br>
  </body>
</html>

--------------020206020509070600040305--
```

Here is the body of the response:

```
--boundary-1381765589
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Our Help Desk cannot respond to individual e-mails, 
but please file a ticket using our web form at
https://fake.fake/fake.
[Your message is attached]

--boundary-1381765589
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------020206020509070600040305"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------020206020509070600040305
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

*Hello*, /world/.

--------------020206020509070600040305
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
      charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <b>Hello</b>, <i>world</i>.<br>
  </body>
</html>

--------------020206020509070600040305--
--boundary-1381765589--
```

Notice that the Content-Type changed from `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` in the original to `text/plain; charset="utf-8"`. I have no idea why it changed.

How can I respond with the original e-mail included in the response so that the recipient can cut and paste the text of their original response?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Clarified what I was asking at the end of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered stripping all the HTML from the message ? You could try 
[https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Strip](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aStrip)